# How can I place delimiters between numbers and text in Python?

Tags: python, text, delimiter

I'm having trouble placing delimiters in the following text.  I want to place a '|' between the text and between each of the 3 subsequent numbers.  The problem is that sometimes the numbers are actually dashes to signify 0 (i.e., -- instead of 0).

```
text = """
A line of text    85         25,653   -75,321
Another - line   5,432     (5,353)     --
Another one      23        -0-       86
One -- more   -- -0- 34 25
"""
```

So far, I can get most of the '|' delimiters, using the following code:

```
text = re.sub(r'\s[(](\d)', '|(\\1', text)
text = re.sub(r'\s(\d)', '|\\1', text)
text = re.sub(r'\s-(\d)', '|-\\1', text)
```

This outputs:

```
A line of text   |85        |25,653  |-75,321
Another - line  |5,432    |(5,353)     --
Another one     |23       |-0-      |86
One -- more   --|-0-|34|25
```

However, I want another delimiter before the second -- in row 4 without placing a delimiter between One and --.  Is there a way to do this in Python?

I would like the final output to be:

```
A line of text   |85        |25,653  |-75,321
Another - line  |5,432    |(5,353)     |--
Another one     |23       |-0-      |86
One -- more   |--|-0-|34|25
```

Comment: Are those tabs between columns in the original file?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the spaces between columns?

Comment: That's not necessary. I just need the first column to be the text column and then have the remaining "number" columns delimited.  The spaces can be removed if necessary, though I'd like to preserve the spacing within the text column (e.g., A line of text, not Alineoftext)

Comment: Do you actually have one row with five columns and the rest with four? Or do they all have the same number of columns?

Comment: Sometimes there are rows with more than 3 columns.  But they are pretty few.  If it would be easy to place delimiters for rows with only 3 columns, I think it wouldn't be too much effort to manually check for rows with 4 columns.

Comment: If there isn't always the same number of columns, and there is a variable amount of whitespace between columns, and columns can contain whitespace, it's _impossible_ to tell where the edge of a column is and what's just whitespace in a column.

Comment: I can manually remove rows with 4 columns so that each row has 3.  The rows with 4 columns are data entry errors anyway and shouldn't be very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python [string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.split()
    if line:
        print '|'.join((' '.join(line[:-3]), '|'.join(line[-3:])))
```

This splits the line wherever there is whitespace, then joins the three data columns with `|`s and the text together with s, then adds a final `|` between the text and the data.

Comment: That works perfectly.  I guess I'll just have to manually check those rows with 4 columns.  Thanks so much.